# Array Insertion Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table item with attributes no(integer) and price(integer), also another table cart with attributes no(integer) and items(array of item).

I have some records in items.

When i tried :

```
INSERT INTO myschema.cart VALUES(1,'{SELECT item from myschema.item}')
```

I'am getting error malformed record literal.

I expected this to insert all items from myschema.item into the cart record.

Comment: `'` denotes a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you exact statement without the table structures and such, but you can select into an array:

```
INSERT INTO myschema.cart (id, item_ids)
SELECT 1, array(SELECT id from myschema.item)
```

This will select the id's from the item table into an array.

You can test it out by writing:

`select array(SELECT id from myschema.item)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a subquery inside a string like that.

What you need to do is aggregate the `item`s into a array with [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
INSERT INTO myschema.cart
VALUES (1, (SELECT array_agg(item) FROM myschema.item));
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO myschema.cart
SELECT 1, array_agg(item) FROM myschema.item;
```